# How to add marker at current location on a Windows Phone App Map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

First of all I'm very new to Windows Phone dev so I might miss something obvious.
I have a ControlMap in my xaml, i'm trying to add marker at my current location. I've gone through many tutorials and I can't only find deprecated ways (tons of using not working) to do it and while it seems simple at first view, I simply can't make it work.

The map in the xaml :

```
    <Maps:MapControl x:Name="LocateMap" Height="221" Margin="0,0,-0.167,0"/>
```

What should I do in the .cs to add this marker ? And where ?
The intent is to store it later, and then print when the app launch all the olds markers + the actual location marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a pin on a specific location (latitude, longitude), do the following steps.

```
  //setting the Map center
  LocateMap.Center = CurrentLocation = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);

  // Create a small circle to mark the current location.
  Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
  myCircle.Fill = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
 myCircle.Height = 20;
 myCircle.Width = 20;
 myCircle.Opacity = 50;

 // Create a MapOverlay to contain the circle.
 MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
 myLocationOverlay.Content = myCircle;
 myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
 myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(lat,
               lon);
 // Create a MapLayer to contain the MapOverlay.
 MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
 myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);

 //adding map layer to the map
 LocateMap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
```